# php/apache asp.net/iis memory usage (process models)?

Tags: php, asp.net, memory

How does the memory usage of php/apache and asp.net/iis compare as the number of simultaneous users connecting increase when running a real world app and how is the memory allocated due to the different process models ?
Examples would be great.

Figures for our current asp.net app show that the asp.net worker process on my dev box is using 69584k, 71520k, 71960 and 75084k for 1, 2, 3 and 4 simultaneous users; I don't know if this is generally representative or not (especially as we consume lots of web services and minimal caching used).

Reason for asking is estimating RAM needed for hosting future applications (in either technology stack).

Cheers Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That totally depends on the complexity and innards of the application. I've seen apps on php/apache that run happilly at 30 - 60 mb for a few hundred concurrent users, and apps that require more then double for a few tenths of concurrent users...

Real world testing/simulation would be advisable...

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for that. What I am trying to understand is how memory usage increases as users increase, e.g. does it jump up proportionally, or is the initial step up then small increases afterwards ?

Comment: Usually small(ish) increases, although it's size can differ as well, again, depending on the 'quality' of the app itself...

Comment: As you've already seen, it's not as simple as {memory = concurrent_requests X constant} not only does it depend on the application it will depend on lots of other factors including such things as the speed of the client connection, the frequency of garbage collection, the amount of free memory on the system....sjon is correct - the **only** way to tell is to take **lots** of measurements from your system and analyse them.